# Erroneous Qt paths of qt libraries on Mac

Tags: macos, qt, path, libraries

I'm having the following situation:

I have built a Qt application on my Mac (it uses certain Qt libraries, like QtSql - it links to them dynamically). The problem is that when I ship the application to another computer (or perhaps it is only "other user"), the application won't execute because of an error, which says that QtSql.framework is missing.

The most annoying thing is that the expected path is /Users/MyUserName/QtSDK/path_to_the_lib_folder. I've gotten to the point where I don't know what I can do anymore to fix it.

I've heard that I can change the default hardcoded paths using a qt.conf file (and added the frameworks into the application bundle). I used it, and in a log file, the QLibraryInfo tells me the correct, modified path. But when I ship it to another computer, I still see the error with "/Users/MyUserName/QtSDK/the_rest_of_the_path" that tells me that the qt framework was not found.

I thought that perhaps I should add the .la file of the framework too, and then thought that I must modify it, etc. but everything I tried, nothing worked.

Comment: You say you use QtSql. Did you ship the driver DLL with your application as well? For example, if you use it in conjunction with a sqlite database, you will need to ship the qsqlite DLL as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do extra steps when deploying for the Mac:

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/deployment-mac.html

and using the qtdeploy script:

http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2007/08/23/deploying-mac-applications-without-the-hassle/

Comment: Like the first link says, Qt now includes a utility called `macdeployqt` that totally handles this. It's probably a much newer version of the 'qtdeploy' in the second link

Comment: Thanks. I have finally used macdeployqt. Though I think it added more things than I needed (like sql odbc when I use only sqlite), it works.